# How to sync database schema changes from source database to destination database in a spring boot application

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate, spring-boot

My requirement is to sync DEV database changes to QA environment.I am using spring boot and hibernate as the ORM is there any way to sync database schema changes and table data changes from DEV to QA.What is the best way

Comment: You can simply take the database dump and load it into your QA server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the direct answer to the current question, but it will make life easier in future in similar situations. It is worth exploring.

It is better if you can use a migration tool and maintain your sql versions properly.

`Flyway` is such tool which will maintain and apply new sql versions to the database everytime you start the server. It will only apply the new versions, everytime you need a change in db, you need to write that sql statement in new version. You can find lot of help online, bellow is the link which explains a bit on how to use it with spring boot.

https://flywaydb.org/documentation/plugins/springboot

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to use [Liquibase](https://www.liquibase.org/), which has a [Hibernate extension](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-hibernate). It worked rather well for us when we were at Spring Boot 1.3.5 and Hibernate 4.3, but I'm having a hard time making it work with Spring Boot 1.4.2 and Hibernate 5.